# How to sort properties on a class using custom property attributes

Tags: c#, sorting, attributes, properties

I have a custom attribute that I apply to properties on a class.  This attribute is used for exporting the class's properties to a flat file.

One of the attribute's properties is `FieldOrder`.  I need to make sure the order in which I export the properties of the class is correct.  Also, not all properties on the class will have the custom attribute.

I found this article: [How do I sort a generic list based on a custom attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231797/how-do-i-sort-a-generic-list-based-on-a-custom-attribute) This solution assumes all properties have the custom attribute, which isn't my case. I was also hoping for more elegant solution.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

```
public interface IFileExport{}

public class ExportAttribute: Attribute
{
    public int FieldOrder { get; set; }
    public int FieldLength { get; set; }
    public ExportAttribute() { }
}

public class ExportClass: IFileExport
{
    [ExportAttribute( FieldOrder = 2, FieldLength = 25 )]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [ExportAttribute( FieldOrder=1, FieldLength=25)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [ExportAttribute( FieldOrder = 3, FieldLength = 3 )]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public ExportClass() { }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public static List<PropertyInfo> GetPropertiesSortedByFieldOrder
                                                            (IFileExport fileExport)
    {
        //get all properties on the IFileExport object
        PropertyInfo[] allProperties = fileExport
                         .GetType()
                         .GetProperties( BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public );
        // now I need to figure out which properties have the ExportAttribute 
        //and sort them by the ExportAttribute.FieldOrder
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I'm ordering the properties by ExportAttribute.FieldOrder Ascending

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe it would be easier to do a simple xml serialization, and then write a library to convert the simple flat xml into a flat file. It would reusable, and you could skip all this custom attribute setup work and reflection.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
public static List<PropertyInfo> GetPropertiesSortedByFieldOrder( IFileExport    fileExport )
{
    PropertyInfo[] allProperties = GetType()
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Select(x => new 
        { 
            Property = x, 
            Attribute = (ExportAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(x, typeof(ExportAttribute), true) 
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Attribute != null ? x.Attribute.FieldOrder : -1)
        .Select(x => x.Property)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Since you didn't explain how you wanted properties without the attribute ordered, I have made it so that they would be at the beginning.  But the gist of this code is:

1. Get the properties
2. Throw them into an anonymous type so you have easy access to both the property and the attribute.
3. Order by the `FieldOrder`, using `-1` for properties without the attribute.  (not sure what you wanted here)
4. Transform the sequence back into a sequence of `PropertyInfo`
5. Convert it into a `PropertyInfo[]` array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of the following options.

First option: pass anonymous function to OrderBy

```
return allProperties.OrderBy(m => m.GetCustomAttribute<ExportAttribute>() == null ? -1 : 
                                      m.GetCustomAttribute<ExportAttribute>().FieldOrder).ToList();
```

Second option: create the function for selecting the key and pass it to OrderBy

```
return allProperties.OrderBy(KeySelector).ToList();
```

The key selector function is defined as in here:

```
    public static int KeySelector(PropertyInfo info)
    {
        ExportAttribute attr = info.GetCustomAttribute<ExportAttribute>();
        return attr == null ? -1 : attr.FieldOrder;
    }
```

If the property does not have ExportAttribute, the selector will return -1. You can choose any other default value.

The second approach lets you define other types of selectors for ordering and just call the new selector you have defined.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [GetCustomAttributes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d.aspx) method on each PropertyInfo to filter the properties with the correct attributes, and then sort the remaining items.

Answer (score 0):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //get all properties on the IFileExport object
        PropertyInfo[] allProperties = fileExport.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        Array.Sort(allProperties, ArrayAttributeComparison);


    }

    private static int ArrayAttributeComparison(PropertyInfo x, PropertyInfo y)
    {
        //Do null checks here
        ExportAttribute xExportAttribute = GetExportAtribute(x);
        ExportAttribute yExportAttribute = GetExportAtribute(x);
        //Do null checks here
        return xExportAttribute.FieldOrder - yExportAttribute.FieldOrder;
    }

    private static ExportAttribute GetExportAtribute(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        object[] attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true);
        foreach (var t in attributes)
        {
            if (t is ExportAttribute)
            {
                return (ExportAttribute)t;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```